# Surname missing in ticket booked for indigo domestic airlines

Tags: air-travel

I have booked a ticket from Bangalore to Goa. My surname is missing, but my ID card contains the surname. For example, my name in the ID card is AA BB CC, but my ticket only has BB CC. My flight is tomorrow. Will it be a problem? Can anyone advise, please?

Comment: I suggest you contact Indigo and ask them if its going to be an issue - they are after all the best source of information in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

You face 2 possible problems when there is a mismatch between your name on the ticket and on your ID. A missing surname is a bigger problem than a missing name.

1. The CISF may not allow you to enter the airport. Their decision is independent of the airline's decision. If they do;
2. The airline may not allow you to board.

Your best option would be to ask the airline to issue a fresh ticket with the correct name and see if they will waive the cancellation fee.